# Why is the number of edges of a $C_5$-free planar graph with $n$ vertices at most $\frac{12n-33}{5}$ where $n\in\{11,12,13\}$?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, extremal-graph-theory

Let us say that a graph is $C_5$-free if it does not contain any cycle $C_5$ as a subgraph (whether induced or not). We define $ex_{_\mathcal{P}}(n,C_5)$ to be the maximum number of edges possible in a $C_5$-free planar graph on $n$ vertices.

Literature [1] proves the following theorem.

**Theorem 3 ([1]).** $ex_{_\mathcal{P}}(n,C_5)\le \frac{12n-33}{5}$ for all $n\ge 11$.

The proof of the theorem uses induction. But the author claims that:

> It can be checked systematically that the result $ex_{_\mathcal{P}}(n,C_{5}) \leq  \frac{12n-33}{5}$ holds for $n \in \{11,12,13\}$ (this turns out to be
> not as onerous as it might at first appear!)

I'm curious as to how the author checked systematically. Using a computer to check them one by one? It seems that the number of $C_5$-free planar graphs of order $11$ (or even more) would not be small.

- [1] Dowden C. Extremal C4‐Free/C5‐Free Planar Graphs[J]. Journal of Graph Theory, 2016, 83(3): 213-230. https://doi.org/10.1002/jgt.21991

Is there a non-computer proof? Or is computer verification really possible (as the number of planar graphs with $13$ vertices is so large)?

Comment: Perhaps with a computer program. It can be done in just a few lines of SageMath code for example.

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis  I tried, and the number of $C_5$-free planar graphs of order $11$ (12, or 13)  is not small. A related question was asked yesterday at ask.sagemath (https://ask.sagemath.org/question/64468/finding-all-non-isomorphic-c_5-free-connected-planar-graphs-of-order-11/)  on this issue. (There's no need to store them, of course.) I feel like there's a theoretical proof here. Or exclude in advance most graphs whose number of edges is obviously not going to reach the upper bound. And then we just need to count the number of edges for a very small number of graphs.

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis Or can you show how this can be done with SageMath? That would be great for me!

Comment: There are 17449299 planar graphs with 11 vertices and 313372298 planar graphs with 12 vertices. (https://oeis.org/A003094) The data for the number of non-isomorphic planar graphs with 13 vertices is not available to me at the moment. We need to go from these planar graphs to  filtering $C_5$-free palanr graphs and  calculating their maximum number of edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof of Theorem 3 is long, but only Part I uses the induction hypothesis and the assumption that there are at least $11$ vertices. In the rest of the proof, we only need to know that there are more than $4$ vertices (to exclude $K_4$) and that there are at least $7$ vertices (so that a bound of $2n-4$ implies the bound we want).

In particular, for $n=7, 8, \dots, 13$, the only potential way to violate the theorem is if the graph $G$ has $\delta(G) \le 2$ or $\kappa(G) \le 1$.

Let's do the following brute-force searches (each of which is considerably less intense because there are fewer than $1000$ graphs to consider in each case):

- When $n \le 4$, $K_n$ is a $C_5$-free planar graph with $\binom n2$ edges. (Trivially but importantly, this is unique.)
- When $n=5$, the $C_5$-free planar graph with the most edges has $7$ edges: one option is $K_{1,1,3}$.
- When $n=6$, the $C_5$-free planar graph with the most edges has $9$ edges: one option is $K_{1,1,4}$.
- When $n=7$, the $C_5$-free planar graph with the most edges has $12$ edges: it is two copies of $K_4$ joined at a vertex. **Importantly, it is unique.**

From here on, we apply the non-Part-I version of the theorem, but also consider the cases where $\delta(G)\le2$ or $\kappa(G)\le1$.

- When $n=8$, the bound $\frac{12n-33}{5}$ gives us $12$ edges. Or, we could have a vertex of degree $2$ or less, in which case we have at most $12+2 = 14$ edges. **However, there is no way to add a degree-$2$ vertex to the extremal $7$-vertex graph without creating a $5$-cycle, so we actually get at most $13$ this way.** Or, we could have a cut vertex, in which case we have at most $\max\{12+1,9+3,7+6\} = 13$ edges. Altogether, our bound is $13$.
- When $n=9$, the bound $\frac{12n-33}{5}$ gives us $15$ edges. Or, we could have a vertex of degree $2$ or less, in which case we have at most $13+2 = 15$ edges. Or, we could have a cut vertex, in which case we have at most $\max\{13+1,12+3,9+6,7+7\} = 15$ edges. Altogether, our bound is $15$.
- When $n=10$, the bound $\frac{12n-33}{5}$ gives us $17$ edges. Or, we could have a vertex of degree $2$ or less, in which case we have at most $15+2 = 12$ edges. Or, we could have a cut vertex, in which case we have at most $\max\{15+1,13+3,12+6,9+7\} = 18$ edges. Altogether, our bound is $18$. **Moreover, the $18$-edge example is unique, since the $12$-edge and $6$-edge pieces we joined along a cut vertex are unique: it must be three copies of $K_4$ joined at a cut vertex.**
- When $n=11$, the bound $\frac{12n-33}{5}$ gives us $19$ edges. Or, we could have a vertex of degree $2$ or less, in which case we have at most $18+2 = 20$ edges. **However, there is no way to add a degree-$2$ vertex to the extremal $10$-vertex graph without creating a $5$-cycle, so we actually get at most $19$ this way.** Or, we could have a cut vertex, in which case we have at most $\max\{18+1,15+3,13+6,12+7, 9+9\} = 19$ edges. Altogether, our bound is $19$.
- When $n=12$, the bound $\frac{12n-33}{5}$ gives us $22$ edges. Or, we could have a vertex of degree $2$ or less, in which case we have at most $19+2 = 21$ edges. Or, we could have a cut vertex, in which case we have at most $\max\{19+1,18+3,15+6,13+7,12+9\} = 21$ edges. Altogether, our bound is $22$.
- When $n=13$, the bound $\frac{12n-33}{5}$ gives us $24$ edges. Or, we could have a vertex of degree $2$ or less, in which case we have at most $22+2 = 24$ edges. Or, we could have a cut vertex, in which case we have at most $\max\{22+1,19+3,18+6,15+7,13+9,12+12\} = 24$ edges. Altogether, our bound is $24$.

We see that for $11 \le n \le 13$, we don't get better bounds from graphs with $\delta(G)\le2$ or $\kappa(G)\le1$ than we do for other graphs (for which the theorem is already known to hold). Therefore the theorem holds when $11 \le n \le 13$.

Comment: A delayed response. Very nice. If I understand correctly, based on your proof, it seems that the author should consider moving Part 1 to the end. Please correct me if I'm wrong. By the way,  the latest article (Kirchweger M, Scheucher M, Szeider S. SAT-based generation of planar graphs[C]//26th International Conference on Theory and Applications of Satisfiability Testing (SAT 2023)) and their program (sat-modulo-symmetries) can generate $C_5$-free planar Turan graphs (very fast). So, I recommend it to you.

Comment: See the link of sat-modulo-symmetries: https://github.com/markirch/sat-modulo-symmetries/  And just run `python ./pysms/graph_builder.py -v 11 --num-edges-low 19 --Ck-free 5 --args-SMS " --planar 5 "` Then it gives a $C_5$-free Turan planar graph. Enjoy it.